# How to get OpenID to *not* ask permission for personal info every login?

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I've just integrated OpenID into my PHP web app using [LightOpenID](https://gitorious.org/lightopenid).

The first time you try to log in with OpenID (through Google, for example) it should (and does) ask for a bit of personal information, such as your name and email address. When they click my "log in with Google" button, it essentially runs this code:

```
$openid = new LightOpenID($app['request']->getHttpHost());
$openid->required = array('namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last', 'contact/email', 'pref/language');
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
return $app->redirect($openid->authUrl(), 303);
```

Which redirects them off to Google, which gives them this prompt:

[image]

And then returns them to my site.

That's all fine and dandy, except that *every* time they try to log in (even after they're registered), Google gives that prompt. I assume it's doing this because I've "required" their name and such. But why would Google keep forcing them to accept if they've already given my app permission? And how would I *not* mark those fields as required if I can't confirm they do or don't have an account until I've got their OpenID identifier?

Answer (score 1):

try $openid->realm

```
$openid = new LightOpenID($app['request']->getHttpHost());
$openid->required = array('namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last', 'contact/email', 'pref/language');
$openid->realm = 'http://your.site.web/';
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
return $app->redirect($openid->authUrl(), 303);
```

Edit: But i don't know if it's work with 'namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last'...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right that Google is displaying because you requested for the information. This is how Google sets up their OpenID workflow, you can't change it.

Some OpenID providers (e.g. myopenid, and the one I built) have a 'remember me' option, that will prevent this prompt from appearing.